# Can someone do an academic PhD after finishing a BBA or an MBA?

Tags: phd, masters, united-kingdom, germany

Can someone be accepted into an academic Ph.D. program after finishing a BBA and/or an MBA and with no other degree?

If so, why? As far as I know, BBA and MBA are professional degrees.

If not, how can they do an academic Ph.D.?

Comment: Do you imply that BBA and MBA are not academic degrees?

Comment: @Nobody, I knew they are *professional* degrees.

Comment: Is there a DBA in those countries as there is in US?

Comment: For clarification: Do you mean only with a BBA/MBA and no other degree, or one of those degrees on top of another degree?

Comment: @Snijderfrey, Yes. You are correct. No other degree.

Comment: @Buffy, DBA is not an academic degree, I guess.

Comment: It could be or not. There is a certain "theory" that backs business structures and actions. An MBA is mostly about practice, but a DBA might be theoretical (i.e. academic).

Comment: Please clarify whether you are asking about changing fields, from business to, say, CS or math or whatever? Germany, at least, can be quite strict about prerequisites. I don't know about UK.

Comment: You will not be accepted to even start an MBA without a BA/BS (or equivalent foreign degree). So I think the premise of your question doesn't hold for the MBA part at least. Also, to your comment above: a DBA is just another word for a Ph.D. - at least if you get it from an R1. If your source is the wikipedia page, the first paragraph has several incorrect statements (e.g., that you need a DBA to teach at a business school, or that the research must be in "business administration." Absolutely not to both.).

Comment: This is Academia SE. What we mean by DBA here is Doctor of Business Administration, not Database Administration. Of course it is an academic degree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually had a friend who did a BBA degree, then he did his Master in ... Astrophysics. He got his PhD in Astrophysics 3-4 years ago at a reputable institution. It was totally possible for him clearly not because professors did not care about his BBA degree, but because they cared about what he did during the undergraduate period (research activities and extracurricular activities related to Astrophysics)

BBA could be a minus, but what you do during your time at college matters more. MBA is probably a **big** minus. However, if you get both a BBA and MBA by coursework and you do nothing else, the odd of getting admitted to a good PhD program is 0.

Furthermore, in some countries, it is not possible to switch field if the master program(s) you are going to apply is too different from what you did in bachelor program.

Comment: Was this in UK or Germany?

Comment: It was France @Buffy. Not too far but not exactly these 2 countries.

Comment: I'll guess the rules are different though.